# Atmosphere push - Securing channels

Tags: primefaces, websocket, push, atmosphere

My question regarding how to secure the channel in an Application using Atmosphere pub/sub.
I'm using Primefaces 3 & GlassFish server for this purpose.

Whenever I create a channel and subscribe to it, I can always see the WebSocket url in cleartext in the dev console/firebug in chrome (for instance). Can somebody sneak into subscribing to my channel? If yes, How can I secure my channel (SSL/Https maybe?). Or do I need to encrypt the channel name whenever I add new one.

Please let me know If I'm not clear with my query.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Anyone? Please let me know if this question is already asked..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use https/wss as URL instead of http/ws (make sure SSL is properly configured with GlassFish)

Thanks

-- Jeanfrancois

Comment: Thanks Jean for your reply. Does this means, apart from having secured URL we don't have any way to actually restrict the (potential hacker) from knowing the name of the channel we're using.?